# Remove Bootstrap WELL padding left and right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any possible to make Bootstrap well close together?

I've tried `clearfix` but still no luck.

What I am trying to do:
[image]
My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I _guess_ you want to eliminate the column padding …?

Comment: is this what you want https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/QgbWqz?editors=1010

Comment: @CBroe like how? Can you give me an example? Padding: 0 -30px?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Wow, that's cool! I've never thought about that. Thank you so much! By the way, is there any other way to do that? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, change the 2px on both the left & right to get the desired gap between them!

```
<style>
  .wellcontainer .col-md-4{
  padding-left:2px;
  padding-right:2px;
}
</style>
<div class="container wellcontainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well">
                <p>Write Something Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```